# What are the primary differences between the Roman Pontificate and the LDS President?

Tags: catholicism, lds, papacy

Both the Catholic and Mormon faiths have a sort of hierarchical structure within their respective Churches. At the top we see two contrasting roles, the Mormon President (filled by people such as Joseph Smith or Brigham Young) and the Roman Pontificate (or the Pope). What are the differences in authority, control, and election of these leaders?

Comment: related [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63486/22319), this might contain what you are looking for

Comment: also [related](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81191/how-do-the-catholic-and-lds-views-of-what-a-prophet-is-differ/81213#81213)

Comment: @depperm is prophet and president interchangeable in this case?

Comment: Yes the president of the LDS church is sustained as prophet, seer, and revelator [source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/general-conference/2021/10/21eyring?lang=eng)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The Roman Pontiff

- is a successor of St. Peter.
- has valid Holy Orders.

Thus, he shares in Christ's authority.

[*Baltimore Catechism* 3](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5045).507:

> Q. How do we know that the bishops of the Church are the successors of the Apostles?
>
> A. We know that the bishops of the Church are the successors of the Apostles because they continue the work of the Apostles and give proof of the same authority. They have always exercised the rights and powers that belonged to the Apostles in making laws for the Church, in consecrating bishops and ordaining priests.

Mormons cannot claim this. Theirs is a man-made sect with solely human authority.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include the role the Mormon president plays in the Mormon church, including his role in defining doctrine and leading the church?

Comment: The argument that Mormonism “*is a man-made sect with solely human authority*” is meaningless. There are many denominations that would say the same of Roman Catholicism.  Similarly the claim that the Pope is in charge because he has “*valid Holy Orders*” is just as refutable, and just as claimable by many other leaders. ¶ This Answer is a good example of the kind of circular reasoning known as the “begging the question” fallacy.

Comment: @RayButterworth I have to agree. Also, Geremia has failed to give the way by which the Pope can define doctrine and answer (if it does) differ from Mormon presidents.

Comment: @Geremia uh… what? I am confused what that has to do with anything. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @LukeHill Anyone can claim to be pope (cf. "[Pope Michael](https://popemichaelfilm.com/)"), but what distinguishes a true pope from a pretender is that a valid pope derives his authority from St. Peter, via apostolic succession.

Comment: @Geremia yea I know that, what does that have to do with my comment?

Comment: @LukeHill "Mormon presidents" are not successors of the apostles, so no matter what they say, they cannot say it with Christ's authority (cf. [Lk. 10:16](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/34757/1787): "He who heareth you, heareth me").

Comment: @Geremia My question was not about the nature of truth regarding either position. My question was on each positions role within their respective churches.

Comment: @Geremia as the LDS claim to be a restoration, they believe the priesthood was restored through Peter, James, and John; the president (as well as all priesthood holders) can trace their authority back to them

Comment: From the [help/on-topic], "As far as the scope of this site is concerned, any group that identifies themselves as Christian *are to be considered on-topic and allowed to label themselves Christian.* Answers are to be judged based on how well they represent the specific view or tradition they claim to speak for, not whether or not you agree with that position. Good answers thoroughly defend a specific viewpoint or accurately describe a broad range of views. Bad answers wrongly represent the view they claim to speak for, are offensive in their demeanor towards other views...."